# Can't login to Spark Cluster on EC2 after the nodes started

Tags: 12.04, server, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to create a cluster of Spark machines. I follow the instruction [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ec2-scripts.html). However, after the machines have started I got this error

```
Setting up security groups...
Searching for existing cluster graph-cluster in region us-east-1...
Spark AMI: ami-35b1885c
Launching instances...
Launched 1 slave in us-east-1a, regid = r-e153a137
Launched master in us-east-1a, regid = r-a352a075
Waiting for AWS to propagate instance metadata...
Waiting for cluster to enter 'ssh-ready' state.............

Warning: SSH connection error. (This could be temporary.)
Host: ec2-54-236-248-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com
SSH return code: 255
SSH output: ssh: connect to host ec2-54-236-248-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com port 22: Connection refused

.

Warning: SSH connection error. (This could be temporary.)
Host: ec2-54-236-248-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com
SSH return code: 255
SSH output: ssh: connect to host ec2-54-236-248-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com port 22: Connection refused

.

Warning: SSH connection error. (This could be temporary.)
Host: ec2-54-236-248-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com
SSH return code: 255
SSH output: Warning: Permanently added 'ec2-54-236-248-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com,54.236.248.xxx' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied (publickey).

.

Warning: SSH connection error. (This could be temporary.)
Host: ec2-54-236-248-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com
SSH return code: 255
SSH output: Warning: Permanently added 'ec2-54-236-248-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com,54.236.248.xxx' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

I'm not sure what seems to be the problem. The pem key is the one I downloaded from Amazon so it should be correct and it has permission `600`. I checked on Amazon Console and the machines have started.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this too but after waiting it out it eventually does connect and finish setting everything up.

After doing some more research it looks like ([from the Amazon Q/A about their Linux](https://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/faqs/)) on initial start up the machines download and install critical security updates and therefore can take longer to launch when that happens.

I am going to modify the ec2 scripts so it will work with Ubuntu ami - right now after testing it gets so far and then tries to execute installs using yum instead of apt-get and ultimately fails if you select an Ubuntu based AMI.